# How do I update to the latest mainline kernel on a server?

Tags: apt, server, kernel, updates, ppa

I'd like to keep an Ubuntu Server 18.04 up to date with the latest mainline kernel. On the desktop I'd just use Ukuu, but I'm looking for a convenient method to use via ssh. I found this: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
Which helps me avoid having to build from source myself, and I could write a script that fetches and installs the latest respective deb files, but isn't there something like that already, such as a ppa?

Comment: I am not aware of anything like what you are asking for. I download and then install the .deb files manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this site, Ukuu has a command line interface which you should be able to use on Ubuntu Server:
[OSTechNix](https://www.ostechnix.com/ukuu-an-easy-way-to-install-and-upgrade-linux-kernel-in-ubuntu-based-systems/)

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. I'll check it out.